# *.bat не воспринимает русский язык

Tags: bat, кодировка

Хотелось бы узнать, каким способом в файлах с расширением .bat можно писать русским языком без иероглифов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
chcp 1251
echo тест
pause
```

Только шрифт консоли нужно поменять на Lucida Console или Consolas

Comment: Как шрифт менять, руками ?

Answer (score 5):

Файлы создаются в кодировке `cp866`, поэтому надо задавать `charset=cp866`.

Comment: не помогает, пишу в блокноте (notepad++)

Comment: пиши тогда в far manager допустим.

Comment: Или напишите программу перекодировки файла из cp-1251 в cp-866.

Answer (score 5):

Мне помогло следующее решение:

```
chcp 65001
echo тест
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, **[вот](http://www.asf.ru/docs/cmd/chcp.htm)** отличная таблица современных кодировок для виндового терминала.

Так, `chcp с параметром 1251` поставит русскую кодировку, т.е `CP1251(Windows-1251)`, а
с параметром 65001 - интернациональную кодировку **UTF-8.**

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо NotePad++. Потому что если поменять кодировку например на OEM 866 и напишите в батнике @chcp 866 то он будет понимать русский язык. Так работает даже если вы поменяете OEM 866 на OEM 855 и @chcp 866 на @chcp 855. (Цифры должны быть одинаковыми). У меня так работает :)

Answer (score 0):

Самое главное нужно понять, есть кодировка текста файла BAT и есть кодировка текста в консоли cmd когда запускается bat файл это две разные вещи. Они должны быть одинаковые!!!!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]